# Where do I store image that I am going to use in my python script?

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to render an image in tkinter.  I have seen many scripts on stack overflow on how to make an image, but when I try that it says that my picture does not exist.  Is there a certain place where I have to store my image?  My python script is saved to the desktop, but I know that python may not search there.  Where do I put the image that I want to show in my program?  Thanks in advance!

Edit: Here is requested code:

```
canvas = Canvas(app, width=300, height=250).pack()
picture = PhotoImage(file='image.gif') #image located in desktop
canvas.create_image(0,0, image = picture
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/theroeloffs/Downloads/myprogram.py", line 87, in <module>
        piper_pic=PhotoImage(file = 'image.gif')
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3306, in __init__
        Image.__init__(self, 'photo', name, cnf, master, **kw)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 3262, in __init__
        self.tk.call(('image', 'create', imgtype, name,) + options)
TclError: couldn't open "image.gif": no such file or directory
```

sorry for some reason this website wouldn't let me make that code

P.S. I have a mac

Comment: Please, show the code there you are trying to use images.

Comment: Cleanest way is to store the path (e.g. `image_dir = ...`) in a config file and import the config file. Read about config files in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it in the same file as your script.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute path to it:

```
picture = PhotoImage(file='/Users/theroeloffs/Desktop/image.gif')
```

Or the better version is, to copy your image to this location:

```
/Users/theroeloffs/Downloads/image.gif
```

(where your script is) and than you can use the file name only:

```
picture = PhotoImage(file='image.gif')
```